# Map annotation swapping from displaying image to default pin randomly

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

When the map is tested through simulator I notice that some annotations display the default pin instead of the customized image. When I go back to the apps Home menu and enter the mapview again the same thing happens with different annotations.

This code present 4 annotations out of 20 that I have which all uses the same code.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[mapView setDelegate:self];
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];

MKCoordinateRegion test1 = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} };
test1.center.latitude = 55.705609;
test1.center.longitude = 13.195707;
[mapView setRegion:test1 animated:YES];

testmap *ann2 = [[testmap alloc] init];
ann2.title = @"test1";
ann2.subtitle = @"Klicka här för mer info";
ann2.coordinate = test1.center;
ann2.name = @"test1";
[mapView addAnnotation:ann2];

MKCoordinateRegion test2 = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} }; //ändra ner
test2.center.latitude = 55.710113;
test2.center.longitude = 13.213500;
[mapView setRegion:test2 animated:YES];

testmap *ann3 = [[testmap alloc] init];
ann3.title = @"test2";
ann3.subtitle = @"Klicka här för mer info";
ann3.coordinate = test2.center;
ann3.name = @"test2";
[mapView addAnnotation:ann3];

MKCoordinateRegion test3 = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} };
test3.center.latitude = 55.708981;
test3.center.longitude = 13.197266;
[mapView setRegion:test3 animated:YES];

testmap *ann4 = [[testmap alloc] init];
ann4.title = @"test3";
ann4.subtitle = @"Klicka här för mer info";
ann4.coordinate = test3.center;
ann4.name = @"test3";
[mapView addAnnotation:ann4];

MKCoordinateRegion test4 = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} }; //ändra ner
test4.center.latitude = 55.705170;
test4.center.longitude = 13.191277;
[mapView setRegion:test4 animated:YES];

testmap *ann5 = [[testmap alloc] init];
ann5.title = @"test4";
ann5.subtitle = @"Klicka här för mer info";
ann5.coordinate = test4.center;
ann5.name = @"test4";
[mapView addAnnotation:ann5];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation

{

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;
static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];




if(annotationView)
    return nil;
else
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation


  reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
   NSString* thisModelName = ((testmap*)annotation).name;

    if ([thisModelName isEqualToString:@"test1"]) {
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test1"];
    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.draggable = YES;
        annotationView.highlighted = YES;

    return annotationView;
    }
    else if ([thisModelName isEqualToString:@"test2"])
    {
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test2"];
        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.draggable = YES;
        annotationView.highlighted = YES;
        return annotationView;
    }
    else if ([thisModelName isEqualToString:@"test3"])
    {
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test3"];
        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.draggable = YES;
        annotationView.highlighted = YES;
        return annotationView;
    }

     else if ([thisModelName isEqualToString:@"test4"])
    {
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test4"];
        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.draggable = YES;
        annotationView.highlighted = YES;
        return annotationView;
    }
    }


     return nil;


     }
```

Comment: Does this issue come from if and else?

Comment: It's not necessary to create and set a region just to set an annotation coordinate.  You could just do `ann2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(55.705609, 13.195707);`.  Only call setRegion (or showAnnotations) once after adding all the annotations to display that area on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting default pins "randomly" because of this code:

```
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

if (annotationView)
    return nil;
```

What this code says is if the `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:`  returns a view (ie. if `annotationView` is *not* `nil`), return `nil` from the delegate method.

When you return `nil` from the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method, the map view does the following:

- If the annotation is of type `MKUserLocation`, it will display the default blue dot.
- If the annotation is not an `MKUserLocation`, it will display the default red pin.

---

What you probably *meant* was:

```
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

if (annotationView)
    return annotationView;
```

***However***, this will create a new problem because if the `dequeue` returns a view (a view that was previously used for a *different* annotation), the `image` of the dequeued view might not match the image that should be used for the current `annotation`.

So what will happen is annotation images will switch around "randomly" as you zoom and pan the map.

The proper approach in `viewForAnnotation` is to:

1. Get a reference to a view using `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:` and if that returns `nil`, create a new view.  Set view properties that are common to all annotations only when creating a new view.
2. Using the view reference obtained in step 1, set view properties that are specific to the current `annotation`.  If a dequeued view is being used, update its `annotation` property as well.

---

Example:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if (! [annotation isKindOfClass:[testmap class]])
    {
        //If annotation is NOT a "testmap" (eg. MKUserLocation),
        //return nil so map view displays default view for it...
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

    if (! annotationView) {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
        //set view properties common to all annotations...
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        //Do not use addTarget with a custom method for callout accessories.
        //Instead, use the calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method shown below.
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        annotationView.draggable = YES;
    }
    else {
        //reusing a view, update its annotation to current...
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    //AFTER we have a view reference, set annotation-specific properties...
    NSString* thisModelName = ((testmap*)annotation).name;

    if ([thisModelName isEqualToString:@"test1"]) {
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test1"];
    }
    else if ([thisModelName isEqualToString:@"test2"]) {
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test2"];
    }
    else if ([thisModelName isEqualToString:@"test3"]) {
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test3"];
    }
    else if ([thisModelName isEqualToString:@"test4"]) {
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test4"];
    }
    /*
     If image name will always be same as `name` property then
     can use single line instead of if/else statements:

         annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:thisModelName];
     */

    return annotationView;
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[testmap class]]) {
        testmap *tm = (testmap *)view.annotation;
        NSLog(@"button for '%@' tapped", tm.name);
    }
}
```